# How to do 2 animations at once with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I'm working on a web project. I want to draw a div element (looks like a table) with an animation: I click on the button, then the div element appears with a small size upon the button, then it floats to "its" posion meanwhile gaining its original size.
I managed to do this, but only sequentely. First the scaling, than the floating. I want these animations to do at the same time.

I use **jQuery ui show()** function to make the div appear and scale to its origin size, then I use the **jQuery animate** fuction for the floating.

I tried to use the **queue : false** property. And I also called the **.dequeue()** function, but it woulnd't work as I wanted so.

I'll appreciate any pieces of advice. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

```
 $('#matrix').animate({
        top: positionTop,
        left: positionLeft,
    });
    $('#matrix').show("scale", { percent: 100, direction: 'both', origin: ['top', 'left'] }, 2000);
    $('#matrix').animate({
        top: positionTopAim,
        left: positionLeftAim
    });
```

Fiddle here: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/r9ukvtou/5/)

Comment: Rather than describe your code, why not provide the code? Preferably in a working example?

Comment: If you have any code, please include it in the question.

Comment: It is something like that [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r9ukvtou/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var $matrix = $('#matrix');
    // store original size
    var size = {
        width: $matrix.width(),
        height: $matrix.height()
    };
    $matrix.animate({
        top: positionTop,
        left: positionLeft,
    });
    // Sets the width and height to 0
    $matrix.width(0).height(0).show();

    // animates into original size
    $matrix.animate({
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height
    }, {queue: false});

    $matrix.animate({
        top: positionTopAim,
        left: positionLeftAim
    }, {queue: false});
```

**queue: false** does the stuff

Here's the [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/r9ukvtou/8/)

For further working with jQuery, prevent yourself from using the same selector twice/more-than once. It's not efficient. There's a formal directive to store the jQuery object into variable called "*$something*".
For more information visit [this site.](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/)

Good Luck ;)

Comment: The problem with this that the table goes to the top after the animation. Really dont know why actually.

Comment: Because your code is animating the same object's attributes at the same time

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Works exactly like I had dreamed previously.